# Laravel tinker not showing opcache working

Tags: php, apache, opcache

This is my OpCache configuration:

```
opcache.consistency_checks => 0 => 0
opcache.dups_fix => Off => Off
opcache.enable => On => On
opcache.enable_cli => Off => Off
opcache.enable_file_override => Off => Off
opcache.file_cache => no value => no value
opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks => On => On
opcache.interned_strings_buffer => 8 => 8
opcache.lockfile_path => /tmp => /tmp
opcache.max_file_size => 0 => 0
opcache.memory_consumption => 128 => 128
opcache.opt_debug_level => 0 => 0
opcache.revalidate_path => Off => Off
opcache.save_comments => On => On
opcache.use_cwd => On => On
opcache.validate_timestamps => On => On
```

and it should be enable then... however I want to be able to check from `php artisan tinker` the status of the opcache, and so something like:

```
> php artisan tinker
  |- opcache_status();
```

However this shows `false`, and from the documentation this means that it's failed

what am I missing?

If I use `php -a` and run something like `print_r(opcache_status());` it prints nothing

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that for some reason, `opcache_status` doesn't work in the console.. in order to check whether it's enable or not, I've used (and it's working):

```
opcache_get_configuration()['directives']['opcache.enable']
```